# Ephesians 4: can women have title of pastor; is it sacrilegious to call a modern day American, “Apostle”

Tags: apostles

We are relocating. Our priority is to find a fellowship. One we visit had females called pastors and their leader was called apostle. We’re uncomfortable with this. As we like the church, can we reconcile these titles biblically?

> Eph 4:11-13 - And it was He who gave some to be apostles, some to be
> prophets, some to be evangelists, and some to be pastors and teachers,
> to equip the saints for works of ministry and to build up the body of
> Christ, until we all reach unity in the faith and in the knowledge of
> the Son of God, as we mature to the full measure of the stature of
> Christ.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for joining the group.  Please remember to take the tour (link bottom left) to better understand how this site is different.  Please nominate a specific verse to examine.

Comment: @Jeff, welcome to the BH forum. My advice is to visit each of the fellowships repeatedly, looking for friendly, enthusiastic people who exhibit the fruit of the Spirit and with bible-based teaching. Some churches teach "verse-by-verse" while others teach "topic-by-topic." The sermons should also include *practical applications* of what's being taught that you can use in your life. I'd look for a church with a humble, Christlike pastor and not a variety show with performers and an audience. Maybe some others here can suggest other qualities that I've missed.

Answer (score 2):

The modern practice of ordaining some church officers, eg. priests, pastors, elders, deacons, etc, to various church functions began in the 3rd century, well after the New Testament was written.  This is not to suggest that the practice is wrong, only extra-Biblical.  Therefore, the debate in many churches about the rules of ordination and when the “laying on of hands” should or should not occur cannot be decided from the Bible because the Bible does not discuss the matter.  Note the following facts:

**FACT #1**:  The New Testament records no instance of any ordination to any office using “the laying on of hands”, or any other rite.  Specifically, the practice of the laying on of hands occurs 31 times in the New Testament:

- 3 times to bless someone (Matt 19:13, 15, Mark 10:16);
- 8 times to arrest someone to put them in prison (Matt 26:50, Mark 14:46, Luke 20:19, 21:12, 22:53, John 7:44, Acts 12:1, 21:27);
- 6 times to receive the Holy Spirit (Acts 8:17, 18, 19, 19:6, 1 Tim 4:14, 2 Tim 1:6);
- 10 times to heal someone (Mark 5:23, 6:5, 8:23, 25, 16:18, Luke 4:40, 13:13, Acts 9:12, 17, 28:8);
- 4 times with an unstated purpose but the context suggests that it was for the reception of the Holy Spirit for a specialized task and/or to bless someone (Acts 6:6, 13:3, 1 Tim 5:22, Heb 6:2).

**FACT #2**:  The New Testament only records elders (or overseers) being appointed to a local church office (Titus 1:5, Acts 14:23, 2 Cor 8:19).  While other church officers are mentioned (eg, apostles, prophets, deacons) there is no record of these being appointed (nor ordained) to their respective offices by a senior bishop or equivalent or anyone else except by God.  Further, the method by which elders were appointed appears to be by election of the congregation (Acts 14:23, 2 Cor 8:19) as is clear from the use of the verb “cheirotoneo” – “to elect by raising the hand” – a practice (and verb) taken from the Greek Senate when voting.  [Note:  The New Testament uses the terms “elder” and “overseer” interchangeably.  Acts 20:17, 28, 1 Tim 3:2, cf. Tit 1:5, 7, 1 Peter 5:1-3]

**FACT 3**:  Our English word “pastor” is from the Latin, “pastorem”, meaning “shepherd”; and thus, is the equivalent of the Greek, “poimen”.  The New Testament makes it clear that elders were to discharge this “shepherding” function (Acts 20:17, 28, 1 Peter 5:2).  However, there is no New Testament instance where a pastor/shepherd is a distinct office from that of elders or apostles.  Further, the New Testament makes no distinction between the “laity” and “clergy”.  Such is a later (but still early) invention.  Put another way, while there are many people in the NT with titles of elder, apostle and prophet, **not a single person is named as “pastor/shepherd”, except Jesus Christ** in Matt 2:6, 1 Peter 5:4, Heb 13:20, John 10:11, 14, 16, Rev 7:17

Therefore, the question is moot.  Asking about the Biblical qualifications of "pastors" is like asking the Bible about the qualifications of dentists - the Bible never discusses this question.

Lastly, I note the following - the NT deliberately makes no distinction between men and women as per the following:

- Women could be significant leaders, eg., Deborah.  Judges 4.
- Women could be prophets of God; eg, Miriam (Micah 6:4, Ex 15:20, 21), Deborah (Judges 4:4), Huldah (2 Kings 22:14-20), Isaiah’s wife (Isa 8:3), Anna (Luke 2:36), Elizabeth (Luke 1:41-45), the four daughters of Phillip (Acts 21:8, 9), etc.
- Women could buy and sell property.  Prov 31:16.
- Women could earn independent income and use it at their discretion.  Prov 31:11, 16, 18, 20, Acts 16:12-15, 40.
- Men were required to treat women and wives with great respect.  In fact, they were to treat wives as Jesus would love them – enough to give His life for them.  Eph 5:25.
- A man could not divorce his wife on whim and marry another without being guilty of adultery.  Matt 19:9 (very different from Roman law), Gen 2:24.
- A man could not deprive his wife of marital privileges.  1 Cor 7:2-4.  (The same was equally required of women.)
- Paul had female co-workers in Euodia and Syntyche (Phil 4:2, 3) as well as Junia the apostle (Rom 16:7).  Nympha appears to be the leader of the church that met in her house at Laodicea (Col 4:15).  John also addressed an epistle to a female church leader (2 John 1).
- In addition to the above, women could hold other offices such as deaconess or “minister” (Rom 16:1).
- The New Testament church was specifically instructed to care for elderly women who could not support themselves.  1 Tim 5:9-13.
- Women were allowed to teach men.  The female leader, Priscilla taught the Apostle Apollos “more adequately”, Acts 18:26.  It is significant that Priscilla is listed before her husband, Aquila, in this passage.  King Lemuel was taught by his mother, Prov 31:1-9.
- Women were permitted to pray and prophesy in public meetings, 1 Cor 11:5.
- Gal 3:28 declares that all gender distinctions are out of place for the Christian congregation

**Apostle**

Our English word, "Apostle" comes from the Greek with almost the same spelling and means, "one who is sent".  Such we might today call "missionaries".  In the NT, there is not a single case of a church or any other human body appointing an apostle - all the apostles in the NT were appointed by God alone.

That is, the apostles in the NT appear to have been appointed on the same basis as prophets.  Put another way, the church cannot elect to have any person have the gift of prophecy or apostleship - that is done by the Holy Spirit, as per 1 Cor 12:7, 8, 9, 10, 11.

Comment: Once again, excellent references and support! For the scholarly minded, I'd strongly recommend Philip Payne's book, *Man and Woman, One in Christ*. His heavily footnoted book covers the the subject thoroughly, including the distigme-obelos symbols in the Codex Vaticanus and the arguments around the first female apostle, Junia. I've heard that some pastors require people to use "Pastor" (as in Pastor Bob etc.) as a formal title when addressing them. I really have no problem with that as long as they address me with my formal title as well, "Saint Dieter." :-)

Comment: I feel like you are deliberately ignoring passages where the NT deliberately makes a distinction between men and women... otherwise useful answer.

Comment: @Austin - do you mean passages like 1 Tim 2:1 & 12, and 1 Cor 14:34, 35?  I have answered those in other questions.

Comment: @Dieter - Good policy.  I insist upon "The Great and Aged Dottard" myself.

Comment: @Dottard, those along with 1 Cor 11  and how as much as Jesus felt free to associate with women he deliberately only chose men to be part of the 12. I don't intend to argue, but I think the statement "that the NT deliberately makes no distinction between men and women may not seem credible to those familiar with these verses and not familiar with your other writings.

Comment: @Austin - we should not make too much (as some do) of the fact that Jesus chose 12 men - he also chose only Jews and Jews from between Jerusalem and Galilee - are these characteristics to perpetuated as well.? The fact remains that numerous women were also an integral part of Jesus' mission.

Comment: @Dottard, I'm not on this comment section advocating one way or another about how one should run a church today, but simply point out that while women were very important and given unusual prominence in Jesus's ministry there are clear and deliberate distinctions made with respect to women by Paul and Jesus (who are both pretty significant to the NT) that call into question accuracy of the definitive statement *"the NT deliberately makes no distinction between men and women "*

Comment: @Austin - that is the way you read it.  I beg to differ on the basis of numerous other references such as Gal 3:26-29, etc.  See my other comments above.  If you wish to differ, why not offer an answer of your own?

Comment: @Dottard, I don't wish to differ further. Thanks for the grace in your responses.

Comment: Jesus came into a society that was highly, even hatefully misogynistic, both Jew and Gentile. A brutal Roman military suppressed the populous, accompanied by a Greek linguistic, cultural, and religious invasion. The land had deep and violent political divisions and was also divided deeply by class. Jesus did not come to change any of this directly, but to confront the root of the problem, demonstrate his authority, and then to sacrifice himself. Imagine the impact on the apostles on who Jesus chose to bear them the news of his resurrection and triumph over death! Was it Peter? James? John? No!